# Photosynthesis and thermosynthesis(?) in plants/organism

Tags: plant-physiology, photosynthesis

A while back I thought to myself: if plants could absorb the entire(or most of) light spectrum as opposed to a narrow range, would it be better/absorb more energy/etc. Recently i read that was not the case because any higher on the spectrum and it could knock electrons loose(or something like that) and any lower and it would generate heat instead. Also the article said that plants focus on specific wavelengths for photosynthesis, hence the colors.

If heat is the main issue, then is it possible to turn the heat energy into usable chemical energy? Potentially allowing plants to absorb a much larger range on the light spectrum? And if the plant could absorb heat as well, would it be cool/cold to the touch?

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically it should be possible for an organism to use hat to produce a chemical that it can then use to make useable energy however at present we know of none that do this. If it is possible though it would allow for life in the warm, dark oceans of Europa and if life is not there already it would make it pretty easy to introduce life permanently to a planet like the moon Europa. However in deep sea vents types of anaerobic respiration are most effective and on the surface light is and so if any organisms ever did use thermosynthesis on earth they were probably outcompete do by other forms of energy production and forced to extinction.

Comment: Welcome to Bio. Could you add sources to your answer?